# Combobox on ajax returned fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, combobox

Alright, I'm developing a system in which you add rows to a table, then enter data into it and save it.
I'm using ajax to return the complete table (which has the input tags). Now, what I'm trying to do is, to use a combobox on a `select` (returned via ajax).
However, this doesn't work. The combobox doesn't function.

Here's an image :-

[image]

Here's my code which returns everything on an ajax request :-

```
...code removed till here (Everything works fine )

while($details = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        //first make the select
        $selectBegin = 
        '
        <select id="combobox">
        <option value=""></option>
        ';
        $innerSelectString = "";
        $selectMain = "";
        while($customers = $s1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            //fix the select thing here
            $si = "<option value='$customers->indexid'>$customers->v1</option>";
            $selectMain .= $si;
        }
        $selectEnd = '</select>';
        $selectFinal = $selectBegin . $selectMain . $selectEnd;
        //select code completed
        $underString =  "
        <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='somename' value='$details->column1'></td>
        <td>$selectFinal</td>
        </tr>
        ";
        $mainString .= $underString;
    }
    $endString =  "</tbody></table>";
    $finalString = $beginString . $mainString . $endString;
    echo $finalString;
```

What might be wrong here? All the files and javascript code is place correctly on the page ajax results are returned.

This is the ajax which returns the fields :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var c = $('#c').val();
//var cu = $('#cu').val();
function load_content_rows()
{
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php?requestid=1",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#requestMaker").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    }); //ajax request end
});
} //load_content
load_content_rows();
```

This is the code for combobox :-

```
<script>
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
The main goal is, if I click on add new row, a new row gets added, the combobox is displayed here, but it doesn't search for any value. Even if I click Show All items, nothing happens.
This needs to work for n number of rows.

Here's the image : 
[image]

Comment: you need to reinitialize `combo box` on newly added element since it will be added to `DOM` on later part.. So you need to show us `ajax` part of `js` and how you initialize first combo box..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao
I've updated my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that `select` returned as response from server has same id `#combobox` which is not right.. So just change it to `class` and once you get the `response` you can do as below to initialize once again:

**php change**

```
$selectBegin = 
'
  <select class="combobox">
  <option value=""></option>
';
...//Rest of the code
```

**ajax change**

```
....  
success: function(response){                    
     $("#requestMaker").html(response); 
     $("#requestMaker").find(".combobox").combobox(); //re-initialize
}
....
```

Comment: Super man! +1, however, it only solved one part of my problem.
Now, when I added another row using my add new row link, it added the new row (all with ajax), the combobox functionality is shown, but however it doesn't search anything. 
This needs to work for n number of rows.
How would this work?

Comment: _doesn't search anything_ can you elaborate what it used to do and how?

Comment: If I enter text *Lo* it returned result *LoValue1*, but, now it doesn't return anything. It neither displays anything when I click on the down arrow (which stands for show all items)

Comment: Do you initialize anything for `search`? and you have written `toggle` functionality which is `toggling` only `#combobox` not `.combobox`. So you need to maintain consistency here..

Comment: I'm really not sure how to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90437/discussion-between-akshay-and-guruprasad-rao).